# Slider bar in GWT

Tags: gwt, slider

Does anyone know if there is a slider bar in gwt? I only found the one from GWT Incubator, which is unfortunately deprecated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is being solved by writing a new lib which uses the jquery slider. The author will release the code when it's stable :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-slider-bar/

With help of this project it is possible create different slider bars.

Comment: An exported copy is available on github - https://github.com/jbarop/gwt-slider-bar

Answer (score 3):

There is no slide bar in the standard GWT library. But an alternative to the GWT incubator is in the sample project [listwidget](http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/) by David Chandler (he's on the Google GWT team). For this sample project he also needed a Slide bar. He took the sources from the GWT incubator and updated them.

What you can do is take these sources and put them in your own project (it has an apache licence). It's maybe not optimal but it worked for me. Here is a link to the sources http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fgwt%2Fgen2%2Fclient (and for convenience here a link to the project: http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/)

Answer (score 3):

You can now just use an HTML5 slider, like this:

```
<input ui:field="sliderInput" type="range" />

@UiField InputElement sliderInput;

sliderInput.setAttribute("min", "1");
sliderInput.setAttribute("max", "100");
sliderInput.setAttribute("step", "10");

Event.sinkEvents(sliderInput, Event.ONCHANGE);
Event.setEventListener(sliderInput, new EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        // sliderInput.getValue();
    }
});
```

Comment: could you please also provide an example which generates the `sliderInput` programmatically, without the use of UIBinder, and adds it to some container widget later?

Comment: @tombo_189 Have a look in the GWT DOMImpl class at the createInputElement method.  Copy that, and change it to have the type of "range".

Comment: If I specify ui:field="sliderInput" to the <input> the GWT compilter return an error:  [ERROR] Template Page.ui.xml has no ui:field attribute for Page#sliderInput

Comment: @Magallo That's odd.  You should be able to add ui:field to any element in the ui.xml.  That's the way to access them in Java.  You might like to check the docs http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slider from smartgwt. You only have to pay attention to the css definition. For the firefox it have to look like this:

```
#isc_4 td{
   font-size:0px;
}
```

The slider is not a html5 slider and not touchable, but it works.

Comment: I need a touchable slider (for ipad). The slider with jquery right now is not touchable but there seems to be workarounds